# Installation Failed whilst installing UBUNTU 13.10

Tags: boot

I have fitted a new from box hard drive into my PC instead of the original 80GB. My PC has 2GB memory installed. I tried installing Ubuntu version 14.04 but failed so I thought it was too advanced for my system. I have now tried to install version 13.10 and I am having the same problem, after going some way of installing to the page where I enter my details and error message popus up saying that the installation has failed (errno 5) regarding bad disks etc. If I opt to try Ubuntu from disk all works fine, I click on icon to install and it goes as far as the screen when I opt to install. What can be the problem? I was running version 12.04 on the old hard drive and all of a sudden the screen went all fuzzy with all the colours spread out. I was not able to boot the PC after so I decided that the hard drive had gone because it could not function. I used Puppy linux disk to gather the information off the disk and tried to install 14.04 onto it, but that was failing also. It does not look like a hardware problem as all seems to be fine. I have checked the contents of the hard drive and all the files look as if they have installed correctly. I have changed the BIOS setting and only get flashing cursor when booting from hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this thread which may help: 
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1910258

Looking at errno 5, that indicates bad I/O (input/output.) If the above doesn't help, I would try to reformat the new drive in gparted since you can run Ubuntu from the disk, and maybe go as far as using fdisk to force the partition off, then go through gparted.

If that fails, I'd hook up the drive and try formatting it from another box, maybe with another OS for a 'second opinion', I like to call it, from another OS's point of view. If nothing then, I'd be worried about a bad logic board on the drive.